The button that has a submenu is not active
If in the context menu an element has a submenu, then when you click on this element nothing happens, naturally only the submenu drops out, you need to make sure that the element with a submenu has a button active, that is, I click on it and the name of this button inserted into Textbox


public class ReasonTemplateTag
{
    public string NameTag { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ReasonTemplateTag> SubMenu { get; set; }
}


<TextBox x:Name="tbTemplate" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
        Style="{StaticResource ParameterTextBoxStyle}"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5 5 10 5"
        cursor:TextBoxBehaviors.Attach="True"
        cursor:TextBoxBehaviors.CaretIndex="{Binding CursorPosition, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Text="{Binding Template, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Tags, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SubMenu}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding NameTag, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Command" 
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                        AncestorType=ContextMenu}, 
                        Path=DataContext.PasteTagsCommand}"/>
                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" 
                            Value="{Binding }"/>
                </Style>
            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>

Tried googling but couldn't find a solution

you need to use proxy because context menu is not in the visual tree, you can see an example here
